# Javascript produces undesirable output

Tags: javascript

I am basically from java background so I wrote a JavaScript code in which a variable act as private variable , Here is my code

```
var myObject = function(){
    var teamScore = 0;  
    return {
        playSix: function() {
            teamScore += 6
        },

        playFour: function() {
            teamScore = teamScore +4
        },

        getScore: function(){
            return teamScore;
        },

        getMScore : teamScore
    }
}();



 myObject.playSix();

alert ("What is the team score  :" + myObject.getScore())
alert ("What is the M-score  :" + myObject.getMScore)
```

Desired output is

What is the team score  : 6 ;
  What is the M-score     : **6**

But the actual output is

What is the team score  : 6 ;
  What is the M-score     : **0**

Why M-score is 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the `getMScore` is initialised to zero, and never changes.

The property `getMScore` is not a reference to the `teamScore` variable, it's only initialised with the value of the `teamScore` variable at the time that the object is created. When the `teamScore` variable is changed, the `getMScore` property is unaffected.

Comment: Thanks ,Such a simple thing , Got It  :)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because `getScore` is a function, and it will get actual result of `teamScore` all the time you call it. But `getMScore` is just simple static value which you have set before returning. Pay attention that `getMScore` is not some kind of "shortcut" or "pointer" to `teamScore`, it's just simple value.

To fix this you should write getMScore as function, for example:

```
getMScore : function() { return teamScore; }
```

and call it like this:

```
alert ("What is the M-score  :" + myObject.getMScore())
```

Answer (score 2):

The getMScore, your are referring to, in `myObject` , is already assigned to 0, when teamscore initially was 0,

So even if you change value for teamscore, it will still return the value which was returned prior to changing the value of teamscore

Answer (score 2):

`getMScore` is initialized with `0`

Because when you defining the `object` the `teamScore` is equal to `0` and `getMScore : teamScore` will also get a `0` doesnt matter you change it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

If you look closely, getScore is a function which when called return the current value of teamScore.
So, when you called myObject.playSix(); teamScore would become 6.
Now calling getScore would return current value of teamScore = 6

On the other hand, getMScore gets assigned to initial value of teamScore (which is 0) and remains the same.
Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

When you *define* the object, you are setting `teamScore = 0` and then `getMScore : teamScore`. In other words, the **value** of `teamScore` will be used to initialise `getMScore`.

Note that "value" is the key word here - this code is not assigning a **reference** to the `teamScore` variable, it's literally just *copying* the current value from one to the other. `getMScore` will not change if `teamScore` does, because the two values are independent.